# How do I format this htaccess rule to not redirect a specific query?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am using an htaccess rule to redirect all urls in the format of:

www.example.com/blog/the-name-of-the-post

to

www.example.com/the-name-of-the-post

So I've removed "blog" from the URL. The redirect rule below is working. However I do not want to redirect any URLs in the format of:

www.example.com/blog/page/x

So if "/page" appears after "blog", then I don't want to do the redirect. The problem is I'm also redirecting the blog pages when paginated.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ https://www.example.com/$2
```

In sum,

www.mysite.com/blog/the-name-of-post redirects to www.example.com/the-name-of-post

www.example.com/page/1 (or page/2, page/3, etc) do not redirect

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to redirect when `page` appears after blog, you can do a negative match for the word `page`, like so:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /blog/(?!page).*$ https://www.example.com/
```

I'm not entirely clear on what all the different possibilities are from your description so I'm just giving you an example of not matching when the word `page` appears in the second position of the URI.